# Create Shipping Labels Error - UPS - Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, shipping, ups

I am trying to create shipping labels through admin->sales->orders->ship

When I select an order, check the "Create Shipping Label" option and then submit shipment is opens a page where I can create packages and add products to the package.

After I have entered the information and click Save I get the following error:

"We don't have enough information to create shipping labels. Please make sure your store information and settings are complete."

I have entered my username, password, access key, and shipper number in the UPS settings under admin->stores->config->shipping-methods.

Is there a way to figure out whats missing or causing the error?

Update

If I go to: https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/manageaccesskeys?loc=en_US

and enter my access key, I get the following table:

```
DEVELOPER RESOURCE                                          ACCESS TYPE

Address Validation - City, State, ZIP                       Production
Address Validation - Street Level                           Production
Dangerous Goods - Package                                   Production
Locator - Package                                           Production
Paperless Document                                          Production
Pickup - Ground Freight                                     Test
Pickup - Package                                            Production
Pre-Notification - Package                                  Production
Quantum View - Package                                      Production
Rating - Ground Freight                                     Test
Rating - Package                                            Production
Shipping - Ground Freight                                   Test
Shipping - Package                                          Production
Time In Transit - Package                                   Production
Tracking - Package, Ground Freight, and Air Freight         Production
UPS Signature Tracking - Package                            Production
UPS TradeAbility - Package                                  Production
```

In the shipping settings for ups in magento I have tried setting `Live mode` to both yes and no but same results

Answer (score 1):

please check if you are using TEST key or PRODUCTION key , there are limitation when using the UPS service for TEST , please debug the request we pass it to the API call when creating the shipping label , and match that request if it is matching with the resource you have uploaded with the image , note that all the array keys which they are asking should match.

Answer (score 0):

Yon need to coordinate with the UPS to allow you to create labels via API. Once it is enabled in your account than you'll be able to create labels within Magento.

Comment: I believe it is enabled. I have updated my question. Any other thoughts or ideas?

Comment: Creating the label is only allowed if you have placed an order using that (UPS).  Other thing to check is shipping origin details and address information are configured for the store.

Answer (score 0):

I think it maybe because of wrong configuration,

Check if your **UPS Type**  is to **United Parcel Service XML** and **Shipper Number** is correct as these are used for making labels.

Comment: The `UPS Type` is set to `United Parcel Service XML`.  I was having a hard time finding the Shipper Number. Eventually I went to `Profile > Payment Options` and there was a field called `Number` under `My Payment Options`. It was 6 digits alphanumeric. I found an article which led me to this number but I am not sure if its correct.

Comment: have you updated it in corresponding field?

Comment: That is the number that I am using for the `Shipper Number` inside Magento. is there is another number I should be using instead? Otherwise the configuration settings should be correct.

Comment: Well, shipper number is alphanumeric  and it is of 6 digit, so idk.

Comment: What is the error you're getting now , place an edit heading in your post and update it there

Comment: the only error I am getting is: `We don't have enough information to create shipping labels. Please make sure your store information and settings are complete.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update store information. Go to Admin -> Stores -> General -> Store Information. After you update all details, you able to create shipping labels from magento.

Answer (score 0):

See below patch.

https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360046750171-Shipping-labels-creation-known-issue-in-Magento-2-4-0

Once you download it, move it to your magento root directory.
Then apply patch with below command
git apply MC-35514-2.4.0-CE-composer-2.patch